# Make whole Div clickable using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

**CODE:**

```
<style>
    .mydiv {
        border: 1px solid #00f;
        cursor: pointer; 
    }
</style>

<div class="mydiv">blah blah blah. 
    <a href="http://examples.com">Examples link</a>
</div>
```

---

I want to click on 'blah blah blah' text and jump to the 'http://examples.com' link using jQuery.

Comment: thanks for replies..but i want the <a> tag inside the div tag

Comment: i can not hardcode the link for window.location.href in js script, as it can be changed on HTML page reload

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JS:

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(){
    if($(this).find("a").length){
        window.location.href = $(this).find("a:first").attr("href");
    }
});
```

OR:

Simply write:

```
<a href="http://examples.com">
    <div class="mydiv">blah blah blah. 
        Examples link
    </div>
</a>
```

Comment: op told that he want a tag inside div tag

Comment: @dholakiyaankit question has been updated after I posted answer. anyways I will update it.

Comment: Yes i know but i just informed you which will definitely leads op to answer +1 from me

Comment: @Hiral- i can not hardcode the link for window.location.href in js script, as it can be changed on HTML page reload

Comment: @user3113862 so you want that on clicking `.mydiv`, it should be redirected to any link within it. is it so??

Comment: @Hiral : yes if i click on text [bla bla] i should be redirected to link that is in <a> tag's href attribute value.

Answer (score 0):

Move the anchor element out of the div to wrap it

```
<a href="http://examples.com">
    <div class="mydiv">blah blah blah</div>. 
    Examples link
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).on("click", ".mydiv", function(){
    location.href = "http://examples.com";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use jQuery to do this, you're looking for the click function.

```
$('.mydiv').click(function(){
    location.href = 'example.com';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do with **HTML**

```
<a href="http://examples.com">
   <div class="yourDiv">blah blah blah. 
      Examples link
   </div>
</a>
```

**but**

if you want to do that with **jquery** do something like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".yourDiv").on('click', function(){
        //As an HTTP redirect (back button will not work )
        window.location.replace("http://www.example.com");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery as was requested:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.mydiv').click(function() {
   document.location.href='http://examples.com';
  });
});
```

OFC, you can (and should) let the browser handle it as suggested by Hiral.

Answer (score 0):

In consideration of the other answers which haven't *yet* been accepted, I assume that you want to use multiple `<div class="mydiv">`, with differing `href` attributes of the `<a>` element.

If the `<a>` element will *always* be the last child of its parent:

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(){
    window.location.href = this.lastChild.href;
});
```

*Remember to remove whitespace and the end of the `<div>`.*

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JAJuE/1/

---

If the `<a>` element will be *somewhere* (though not necessarily at the end) in the `<div>`:

**HTML**

```
<div class="mydiv">blah blah blah.
    <a href="http://examples.com" class="mylink">Examples link</a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(".mydiv").click(function(){
    window.location.href = this.getElementsByClassName("mylink")[0].href;
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JAJuE/